# Can a pointer be formed to a non-addressable function from STD in an unevaluated context?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, function-pointers

As stated in [namespace.std#6](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#6):

> Let F denote a standard library function ... Unless F is designated an addressable function, the behavior of a C++ program is unspecified (possibly ill-formed) if it explicitly or implicitly attempts to form a pointer to F. ...

Which means for the following program:

```
#include <cctype>
auto f = &std::tolower;  // bad
```

the behavior is unspecified, and the program is possibly ill-formed. (`std::tolower` is not an addressable function).

However, is the following program well-formed and/or is the behavior specified?

```
#include <cctype>
using u = decltype(&std::tolower);  // good?
```

Here, the forming of the pointer to the function is done in an unevaluated context, and so it seems reasonable that I could just get the type of the function pointer. In this case, I expect `u` to just be `int (*) (int) noexcept`. Is this valid?

Comment: It looks good on my machine.

Comment: @lakeweb Sure, but that doesn't mean the code is legal. In fact, I'm pretty sure the first program will compile, and appear to work on your machine as well, but that program is broken.

Comment: As it is just a type, I'm not sure it would be any different than `using y = int(*)(int i);`, which I've done in the past.(being sure is above my pay grade :)

Comment: @lakeweb I believe the standard explicitly disallows taking addresses of functions from the `std` namespace. Whether it applies to unevaluated contexts though is an interesting question, though I would presume it does.

Comment: Hi @Sopel thanks for the clarification. So my vote, as this is not reaching for implementation, it should be perfectly valid.

Answer (score 7):

The intent is that this is **invalid**.  The point of the rule is to allow implementations to do things like add parameters with default arguments or provide additional overloads.  These things, done properly, are invisible to *calls* of the function but misbehave when the function *itself* is examined—especially if the overloads cause there to be no singular “itself”.  None of this has to do with evaluation: it happens during overload resolution for the function name.

That said, the wording could be clearer: the mixed descriptions of compile- and run-time behavior confuse the question as to whether the evaluation of the identity of the function is what is problematic.