# Questions about `std::cout << &std::hex << 123 << std::endl;`

Tags: c++

Here is the [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/orb37szPq):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::hex << 123 << std::endl;

    std::cout << &std::hex << 123 << std::endl;
}
```

1. What's `&std::hex`?  I think it acquire the address of `std::hex`. And the address would be printed out.
2. Is there any potential problem with this code snippet because [somebody said it's bad to acquire the address of a function provided by the standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687044/can-i-take-the-address-of-a-function-defined-in-standard-library)?

Comment: The question in my mind is why would you or what would motivate you to use `&std::hex` instead of just `std::hex` as is the normal usage in this context?

Comment: One reason questions are limited to one question each is to make tracking questions and answers simpler. In this case, your first question appears to be a duplicate of [Why do function pointer definitions work with any number of ampersands '&' or asterisks '*'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893285/) and your second a duplicate of [the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687044/) combined with [the list of designated addressable functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Designated_addressable_functions), which contains `std::hex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of a function decays into a pointer to that function. So `std::cout << std::hex` uses the stream inserter that takes a pointer to a function that takes an `std::ios_base&` and returns an `std::ios_base&`. The stream inserter simply calls the function.

Function pointers have another peculiar property: when you write `&std::hex`, it evaluates to the address of the function. Same for `&&std::hex`, `&&&&std::hex`, etc. They all mean the same thing.

Comment: is the `$` a typo?  I don't even think that `&&std::hex` is valid C++. So I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Then what about the second question?

Comment: @John in this case, `std::hex` and other I/O manipulators are designated as *addressable functions*, so taking their address is allowed. See the "Addressing restriction" section @ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std

Comment: @Pete Becker `&&std::hex` do not compile! https://godbolt.org/z/shPhdsfx1

Comment: I think you got it confused with `*****std::hex` with the implicit function-to-pointer conversion before every pointer indirect. `&&` in clang/gcc is parsed as a special "address-of-label" operator, and even `& &std::hex` doesn't work because it tries to take the address of the rvalue function pointer `&std::hex`

Comment: @RemyLebeau What are the main differences between addressable functions and non-addressable functions?

Comment: @John the C++ standard does not allow you to take the memory address of non-addressable functions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Why? What are the benefits of not allowing to do so?

Comment: @John https://stackoverflow.com/a/66524080/65863

Comment: @RemyLebeau  How to understand [`basic_ostream& operator<<(std::ios_base& (*func)(std::ios_base&) );`  calls `func(*this)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)? `std::cout<<&std::hex` is equivalent to `std::cout(std::hex)`?

Comment: @John `std::ios_base& (*func)(std::ios_base&)` is a pointer named `func`, that points to a function taking a `std::ios_base&` as a parameter and returning a `std::ios_base&`. This `operator<<` simply calls the pointed-at function, passing `*this` as the parameter. `&std::hex` takes the address of (returns a pointer to) the `hex` function. Referring to `std::hex` by just its name decays into a pointer to the `hex` function. Thus, `std::cout<<&std::hex` and `std::cout<<std::hex` are both equivalent to calling `std::hex(std::cout)`.